# How to stop HashRouter overrites the URL in its format

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We're integrating React to our current front-end framework.
New to react-router-dom.
How do I stop Hashrouter to change our URL format from

http://localhost:8080/#myApp/react/products/1

to

http://localhost:8080/#/myApp/react/products/1

I don't want this # position change on our product. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change `HashRouter` to [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter)

So instead importing it and using

```
<HashRouter/>
```

do

```
<BrowserRouter/>
```

you import it the same way.